# Unable to load .bmp files win32

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap

I have been wanting to create a small application wherein the user could load .bmp images and load audio files concurrently (multi-threading). However, as I am not very familiar with win32, I seem to be having a problem loading a .bmp file. EDIT: It seems like my problem has to do with the "szFileName" variable not receiving any data through the OpenFileDialog function. In the case ID_FILE_LOADIMAGES, the "szFileName" is testing false even after the user has chosen a certain bmp image and clicked ok. I do not know why that is occurring.

```
#include "resource.h"
#include <windows.h>

// Global Variables
HINSTANCE g_hInst;
LPTSTR szFileName;
HBITMAP hBitmap;
BITMAP bitmap;
RECT rect;
HDC hdc, hdcMem;
static OPENFILENAME ofn;
bool g_bhBitmap = false;

// Function Prototypes
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
void InitialiseDialog(HWND hwnd)
{
    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
    ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
    ofn.hInstance = NULL;
    ofn.lpstrCustomFilter = NULL;
    ofn.nMaxCustFilter = 0;
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 0;
    ofn.lpstrFile = (LPWSTR)szFileName;
    ofn.nMaxFile = 500;
    ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
    ofn.nMaxFileTitle = MAX_PATH;
    ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
    ofn.lpstrTitle = NULL;
    ofn.Flags = 0;
    ofn.nFileOffset = 0;
    ofn.nFileExtension = 0;
    ofn.lpstrDefExt = NULL;
    ofn.lCustData = 0L;
    ofn.lpfnHook = NULL;
    ofn.lpTemplateName = NULL;
}
BOOL OpenFileDialog(HWND hwnd, LPTSTR pFileName, LPTSTR pTitleName)
{
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
    ofn.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    ofn.lpstrCustomFilter = NULL;
    ofn.nMaxCustFilter = 0;
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 0;

    ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
    ofn.lpstrFile = pFileName;
    ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
    ofn.lpstrTitle = pTitleName;
    ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = TEXT("Bitmap Files (*.bmp)\0*.bmp\0\0");

    return GetOpenFileName(&ofn);
}

//...Window Creation...

// Load bitmap and check for errors
bool LoadAndBlitBitmap(LPCWSTR szFileName, HDC hWinDC)
{
    // Load the bitmap image file
    hBitmap = (HBITMAP)::LoadImage(NULL, szFileName, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);

    // Verify that the image was loaded
    if (hBitmap == NULL) {
        ::MessageBox(NULL, L"LoadImage Failed", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    // Create a device context that is compatible with the window
    HDC hLocalDC;
    hLocalDC = ::CreateCompatibleDC(hWinDC);
    // Verify that the device context was created
    if (hLocalDC == NULL) {
        ::MessageBox(NULL, L"CreateCompatibleDC Failed", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    // Get the bitmap's parameters and verify the get
    BITMAP qBitmap;
    int iReturn = GetObject(reinterpret_cast<HGDIOBJ>(hBitmap), sizeof(BITMAP),
        reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(&qBitmap));
    if (!iReturn) {
        ::MessageBox(NULL, L"GetObject Failed", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    // Select the loaded bitmap into the device context
    HBITMAP hOldBmp = (HBITMAP)::SelectObject(hLocalDC, hBitmap);
    if (hOldBmp == NULL) {
        ::MessageBox(NULL, L"SelectObject Failed", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    // Blit the dc which holds the bitmap onto the window's dc
    BOOL qRetBlit = ::BitBlt(hWinDC, 0, 0, qBitmap.bmWidth, qBitmap.bmHeight,
        hLocalDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    if (!qRetBlit) {
        ::MessageBox(NULL, L"Blit Failed", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    // Unitialize and deallocate resources
    ::SelectObject(hLocalDC, hOldBmp);
    ::DeleteDC(hLocalDC);
    ::DeleteObject(hBitmap);
    return true;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        InitialiseDialog(hWnd);
        return 0;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
        wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);

        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case ID_FILE_LOADIMAGES:

            OpenFileDialog(hWnd, szFileName, L"Open a Bitmap File.");

            if (szFileName)
            {
                ZeroMemory(&hBitmap, sizeof(HBITMAP));
                LoadAndBlitBitmap(szFileName, hdc);
            }

            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
            return 0;

            break;
        case ID_FILE_LOADAUDIO:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        case ID_FILE_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        if (g_bhBitmap)
        {
            LoadAndBlitBitmap(szFileName, hdc);
        }

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        if (hBitmap)
            DeleteObject(hBitmap);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: "I seem to be having a problem" is not an appropriate problem description.

Comment: It seems to me that the actual problem is that you don't know how to, or have chosen no to, debug your code. Please try to rectify whichever of these applies.

Comment: "here is my whole code so far" - Please read How to create a [mcve]

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry, I'm just a new registered user looking for assistance. I was simply hoping someone would tell me how I should be utilizing the OpenFileDialog. Also I know how to write minimal code, but I thought it was important for people to see the whole thing in order to assist me to an adequate degree. Thanks for your comments though.

Comment: I have followed your guidelines and enhanced my question a little bit and removed an unnecessary chunk of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you never allocate a buffer for the filename.
The different data types can [be found in this SO answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/194768).

Your `szFileName` is defined as an

> LPTSTR = char* or wchar_t* depending on _UNICODE

so it's a pointer, but in your code sample you didn't reserve memory for this pointer.

```
ofn.lpstrFile = (LPWSTR)szFileName;        // in WndProc
LoadAndBlitBitmap(LPCWSTR szFileName...)   // passed as CONST 
LoadImage(NULL, szFileName...)             // passed as parameter
OpenFileDialog(hWnd, szFileName, ...)      // passed as parameter
if (szFileName) ...                        // check if !NULL
LoadAndBlitBitmap(szFileName, hdc);        // passed as parameter
```

But you never allocate the necessary memory to the pointer...

In the [`OPENFILENAME` structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646839(v=vs.85).aspx) `lpstrFile` is defined as:

> The file name used to initialize the File Name edit control.
>   The first character of this buffer must be NULL if initialization is not necessary.
>   When the GetOpenFileName or GetSaveFileName function returns successfully, this buffer contains the drive designator, path, file name, and extension of the selected file...
>
> If the buffer is too small, the function returns FALSE and the CommDlgExtendedError function returns FNERR_BUFFERTOOSMALL. In this case, the first two bytes of the lpstrFile buffer contain the required size, in bytes or characters.

So you simply need to assign a buffer to `szFileName` to fix that problem.

That will solve your

> In the case ID_FILE_LOADIMAGES, the "szFileName" is testing false even after the user has chosen a certain bmp image and clicked ok.

problem. It returns `FALSE` because your "buffer" (=none) is too small.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I have fixed the problem and I can now load a bitmap image by changing `LPTSTR szFileName;` to `char szFileName[MAX_PATH];` However, I cannot select multiple bitmaps at once, is there a way I could make it so that I could load multiple images at once? Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how my declaration looks like right now, but even with the `OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT;` it won't let me load multiple images at once, which is what I want. :(

```
 char szFileName[MAX_PATH];

BOOL OpenFileDialog(HWND hwnd, LPTSTR pFileName, LPTSTR pTitleName)
{
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
    ofn.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    ofn.lpstrCustomFilter = NULL;
    ofn.nMaxCustFilter = 0;
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 0;

    ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
    ofn.lpstrFile = pFileName;
    ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
    ofn.lpstrTitle = pTitleName;
    ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = TEXT("Bitmap Files (*.bmp)\0*.bmp\0\0");

    if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn) != TRUE)
        return FALSE;
    else
        return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, fixed the problem, turned out I had `ofn.flags = 0;` elsewhere. So it was overwriting the `ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT;`